# Can't parse JSON get from PHP in iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I'm developing an app that needs to send request to web service and obtain JSON for the next process. I'm using `AFNetworking` for the request. Following is my PHP code

```
$data = array(
            array(
                'userID' => 'xxx'
            )
        );
echo json_encode($data);
```

I've already verified the above code, and the result printed is fine.

```
[{"userID":"xxx"}]
```

Then, I use `AFNetworking` to send a request for this Json data as below

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"action": @"verifyUDID", @"UDID": udid};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];

[manager POST:@"http://roommateradar.com/RoommateRadarAPI.php"  
         parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

             NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
             NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

The `NSLog` is correctly show the `JSON` data, but the next line which is parsing `JSON` to NSDictionary will cause a crash, the output is like below

```
2014-04-10 21:59:56.893 RoommateRadar[2941:60b] (
        {
        userID = xxx;
    }
)
2014-04-10 21:59:56.893 RoommateRadar[2941:60b] -[__NSCFArray bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1493e660
2014-04-10 21:59:56.895 RoommateRadar[2941:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1493e660'
```

So you can see that the NSLog(@"%@",responseObject); is actually showing correct thing. BTW, I also tried

```
[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:responseObject];
```

to verify the responseObject, the result is also valid.

Any little help?

Comment: Because you are getting array from service so get NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]; and then get NSDictionary *dictT = [arr objectAtIndex:0]; and then do NSLog("%@",dictT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFNetworking already deserialises the `responseObject` for you, so you don't need to use `NSJSONSerialization`.

The crash is because you are passing the deserialised `NSArray` to `NSJSONSerialization` when it expects `NSData`.

Also, when you do:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization ...
```

you would not get a dictionary anyway, you would get an array. You should just have:

```
NSArray *users = (NSArray *)responseObject;
NSDictionary *user = [users objectAtIndex:0];
```

(obviously you need to check the `users` array `count`)

Also, when you use `isValidJSONObject:`, you're using it the wrong way round. It verifies if an object can be converted *into* JSON, not if the object can be converted from JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right, AFNetworking has already deserialized the JSON for me. Now I can get the userID from responseObject. However, When I try to get the userID from the NSArray users like `[users objectAtIndex:0]`, it cause a crash again. Instead, `I use NSDictionary *users = [responseObject objectAtIndex:0]` and then it works for '[users objectForKey:@"userID"]`